# Check if I can show a dialog (based on current code is running in a winform app OR windows service)

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have some shared code I need to use both in a WinForm and a service. How can I test if my code is running in a service, so I can avoid problems with modal dialogs.

Comment: You might consider just adding an (optional) `silent` Boolean parameter to your shared code. This allows for more flexibility, and you avoid cluttering your "business logic code" with environment-specific dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be enough for you to test the [Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) property, and only show the dialog if this is true.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I spent a long time googling it, but then it was as simple as that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. `System.Environment.UserName` is `SYSTEM` or `Network` then most possibly it is a service.
2. Check callstack and see if very first method called belongs to the class derived from `ServiceBase`
3. You could also check `Process.SessionId` to be **0** because all system processes & services run under session 0.